# Implementing custom partitions for s3 kafka connect sink

Tags: apache-kafka-connect, s3-kafka-connector

I want to implement a custom s3 partitioner class to include some avro message fields and some extra logic to generate the output s3 path prefix

The project is in kotlin, this is my class:

```kotlin
package co.kafkaProcessor.connect

import io.confluent.connect.storage.errors.PartitionException
import io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner
import org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException
import org.apache.kafka.connect.sink.SinkRecord
import org.joda.time.DateTime
import org.joda.time.DateTimeZone
import org.slf4j.Logger
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory

class MachineAwareHourlyPartitioner<T> : TimeBasedPartitioner<T>() {
    private val log: Logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MachineAwareHourlyPartitioner::class.java)
    private lateinit var environmentName: String

    override fun configure(config: MutableMap<String, Any>?) {
        super.configure(config)
        environmentName = config!!["environment.prefix"] as String
    }

    private fun encodedPartitionForTimestamp(sinkRecord: SinkRecord, timestamp: Long?): String? {
        // Our custom logic goes here
    }
}
```

at first I've tried by creating a custom shadowJar task to generate the Jar file:

```
tasks {
    withType<ShadowJar> {
        mergeServiceFiles()
        append("META-INF/spring.handlers")
        append("META-INF/spring.schemas")
        append("META-INF/spring.tooling")
        transform(PropertiesFileTransformer::class.java) {
            paths = listOf("META-INF/spring.factories")
            mergeStrategy = "append"
        }
    }

    // Custom jars for kafka connect
    create<ShadowJar>("kafkaConnectUtilsJar") {
        archiveClassifier.set("connect-utils")
        include("co/kafkaProcessor/connect/**")
        include("co/kafkaProcessor/serializer/**")
        from(project.sourceSets.main.get().output)
        configurations = listOf(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.get())
    }
}
```

but doing `jar -tvf filename.jar` showed that it only included my own code and kafka connect failed with `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.TimeBasedPartitioner`.
I thought that you're not supposed to include kakfa connect code in your custom jar, also because if I try to configure the task with `TimeBasedPartitioner` it works so the class is available.

I've then tried to include the storage partitioner too by changing the custom jar definition to:

```
tasks {
    withType<ShadowJar> {
        mergeServiceFiles()
        append("META-INF/spring.handlers")
        append("META-INF/spring.schemas")
        append("META-INF/spring.tooling")
        transform(PropertiesFileTransformer::class.java) {
            paths = listOf("META-INF/spring.factories")
            mergeStrategy = "append"
        }
    }

    // Custom jars for kafka connect
    create<ShadowJar>("kafkaConnectUtilsJar") {
        archiveClassifier.set("connect-utils")
        dependencies {
            include(dependency("io.confluent:kafka-connect-storage-partitioner:10.2.4"))
        }
        from(project.sourceSets.main.get().output)
        configurations = listOf(project.configurations.runtimeClasspath.get())
    }
}
```

this includes all my application code unfortunately, but I can see the partitioner being included in the jar file.

Kafka connect now fails with this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class co.kafkaProcessor.connect.MachineAwareHourlyPartitioner cannot be cast to class io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.Partitioner (co.kafkaProcessor.connect.MachineAwareHourlyPartitioner is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; io.confluent.connect.storage.partitioner.Partitioner is in unnamed module of loader org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.isolation.PluginClassLoader @63a6dffd)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.newPartitioner(S3SinkTask.java:196)
        at io.confluent.connect.s3.S3SinkTask.start(S3SinkTask.java:117)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerSinkTask.initializeAndStart(WorkerSinkTask.java:312)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.doRun(WorkerTask.java:186)
        at org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.WorkerTask.run(WorkerTask.java:243)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829)
```

Update: I've also tried to change how the function was overridden by overriding the public methods `encodePartition` however that didn't change.

I've also tried to add a test like this (that hopefully should try to cast to Partitioner`:

```
val partitioner = MachineAwareHourlyPartitioner<String>()
val implementedPartitioner = partitioner as Partitioner<String>
```

which didn't fail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get the partitioner working by adding my jar file (without any included dependencies) into the s3 connector directory:

```
/usr/share/confluent-hub-components/confluentinc-kafka-connect-s3/lib/
```

I'm not sure if this is related to the plugin isolation that avoids libraries from different plugins to interfere to each other but in my original try I had the plugin in the main classpath `/usr/share/java/kafka/` which I thought would made it available to every plugin

Just as an extra detail, we also use another custom class to override the avro `TopicNameStrategy` which didn't work in the s3 connector folder, I had to copy the jar also in the `/usr/share/java/kafka/` directory to fix this, not sure why one works in the global folder and the other doesn't

Comment: If someone else has a better and more in depth explanation I'll be happy to mark that as an answer